# Rails - moving controller logic into a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller, logic

I'm looking to clean up my controller, as it seems heavy and redundant. Any help on how I'd go about moving this type of logic into my model would be appreciated.  Thanks for any help on this - the code below is my for index action:

```
case params[:find_by]
  when 'topic'
    nuggets = Nugget.where(['topic = ?', params[:topic_name]])
    @nuggets = nuggets.paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 15)
    @title = nuggets.first.topic
  when 'audience'
    nuggets = Nugget.where(['audience = ?', params[:audience_name]])
    @nuggets = nuggets.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    @title = nuggets.first.audience
  else
    @nuggets = Nugget.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
end
```

Comment: Looks like something like MetaSearch, MetaWhere, or Ransack could help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I *would* move it into the model. I'd probably just move it into a private utility method in the controller.

```
case params[:find_by]
  when 'topic'
    nuggets = Nugget.find_by_topic(params[:topic_name])
    @title = nuggets.first.topic
  when 'audience'
    nuggets = Nugget.find_by_audience(params[:audience_name])
    @title = nuggets.first.audience
  else
    nuggets = Nugget.all
end

@nuggets = Nugget.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
```

Another option would be to create routes for the different finds; whether or not it's worth it, meh. You *could* move the find_by logic into the model, or use a `send` to slightly DRY up the topic/audience difference, but again, that seems more trouble than it's worth.

I'll be interested to see what more Rails-y people think about the question, though.

Comment: Thanks Dave - based on what I need to do, I'm going to create separate routes. I played around with it for a bit and found that to be my best option - thanks for the input!

Comment: @Gavin No problem--sometimes it's the cleanest, easiest-to-maintain thing to do, for better or worse.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your model

```
def self.topic(topic_name)
    where(:topic => topic_name)
end

def self.audience(audience_name)
    where(:audience => audience_name)
end
```

And in the controller replace with this

```
def index
    if params[:find_by]
        nuggets = Nugget.send(params[:find_by].to_sym)(params[:name])
        @nuggets = nuggets.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    else
        @nuggets = Nugget.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    end
    @title = @nuggets.first.send(params[:find_by].to_sym)
end
```

You will just need to use same parameter key for audience and topic

Comment: I find that less obvious and more difficult to read than the naive solution (which is why I only mentioned it in passing in my answer).